# Jenkins hosted on VM, not able to fetch Azure resource group names, for a free style project

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-resource-group, azure-vm, azure-service-principal

I don't know why this issue is happening, but I am confident that the configuration was done properly.
I created an Azure VM, installed Jenkins in that, and created a freestyle project. And Then I added the git and Azure Service Principle credentials to the global unrestricted access to Jenkins credentials (system). When I try to add a post-build setup of publishing to an azure web app, I get the following errors.
I have added images, please open the links and look into them, and help me out.

As you can see, the service principle has been successfully verified.

[image]

But in the second picture, when I try to access the resource group, it says none, even though I have created a resource group, app service plan, app services etc.

[image]

Comment: I tested in my enviroment and facing the same Issue, Did few reaseach and found that   **Azure App Service Plugin** is up for  adoption and under maintaiance. The Same issue is happing with other Azure plugin as well like **Azure Storage**,**Azure Cosmos** . For more information you can check this [Document](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-app-service/).

Comment: In the same document you can even find how to install the plugin manually along with the steps you can even try that as well.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT were you able to resolve the error, by manually installing the plugin?

Comment: Since it been not officially realease, When i tried to download the maven repro for Azure App Service plugin in my system it is asking me enter credential for the repro **https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/**.You need to contact to Jenkins Support, how you can access the plugin manually.May they can help or you have to wait till it official release.

Comment: Link for [Azure App Service plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/azure-app-service/1.0.1), You can try in your system to download.

Answer (score 0):

***I tested in my enviroment and facing the same Issue,Even after Succefully verified the service principle.***

[image]

[image]

Did few reaseach and found that Azure ***App Service Plugin*** is up for adoption and under maintaiance and few of them as been deprecated and also they are looking for new maintainer. The Same issue is happing with other ***`Azure plugin`*** as well like ***[Azure Storage](https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-azure-storage/),[Azure Cosmos](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-commons/)*** and many more...

Even though in the document its stated you can install the Azure App Service plugin manually before officially release but when i tried to install the maven repro its prompting for enter the credential to download the repro. Seems its private repro we can't access.

[image]

For Workaround for this issue or for more information you can reach out to ***[Jenkins Community Team or Support](https://www.releaseteam.com/jenkins-support/)***.